# Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'account.Account'

Tags: python, django

I get always the error 
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'account.Account'

When I go on http://127.0.0.1:8003/register everything works, when I press the "submit" button i get that error. I tried different solutions but still I can't understand the error.

account/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from account.models import Account


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email','username','date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin','is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email','username',)
    readonly_fields=('date_joined', 'last_login')

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()


admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

account/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm  #CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


from account.models import Account

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Add a valid email address.')

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

account/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.registration_view, name = 'register'),

]
```

account/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from account.forms import RegistrationForm


def registration_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('quiz')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')


def login_view(request):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("quiz")

    if request.POST:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("quiz")

    else:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    # print(form)
    return render(request, "account/login.html", context)
```

quiz/settings.py

```
"""

import os




DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'quiz',
    'account',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'quizapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL='account.Account'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'quizapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/excepti
on.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py
", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py
", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/Users/utente/Dropbox/sperem copia 2/account/views.py", line 10, in registration_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line
 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line
 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line
 378, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py
", line 123, in _post_clean
super()._post_clean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", lin
e 404, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", l
ine 1207, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.p
y", line 366, in clean
    self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py"
, line 188, in __get__
    cls._meta.swapped,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'account.Account'
[05/Apr/2020 12:43:08] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 98061
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question?

Comment: ok, i've done it

Comment: Is your forms.py indented correctly? The `Meta` should be defined in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation of your error is the indentation in the form. I think it is not done correctly, hence the Meta class of `UserCreationForm` is not overridden. You can fix that by:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Add a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', )
```